# Continuing in a range-based for loop doesn't retrigger breakpoints?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, for-loop, gdb

I'm teaching a programming course where we'll be using C++. I was putting together a handout about how to use the debugger and wanted to have students step through the execution of this hash code generator for first and last names:

```
int nameHash(string first, string last){
    /* This hashing scheme needs two prime numbers, a large prime and a small
     * prime. These numbers were chosen because their product is less than
     * 2^31 - kLargePrime - 1.
     */
    static const int kLargePrime = 16908799;
    static const int kSmallPrime = 127;

    int hashVal = 0;

    /* Iterate across all the characters in the first name, then the last
     * name, updating the hash at each step.
     */
    for (char ch: first + last) {
        /* Convert the input character to lower case, then make sure it's
         * between 0 and the small prime, inclusive.
         */
        ch = tolower(ch) % (kSmallPrime + 1);
        hashVal = (kSmallPrime * hashVal + ch) % kLargePrime;
    }
    return hashVal;
}
```

Using gdb, I set a breakpoint on the line containing the range-based for loop:

```
(*) for (char ch: first + last)
```

When I ran the program with gdb and as expected it triggered a breakpoint here. However, if I then continue execution, the breakpoint does not retrigger and the program runs to completion.

I can reproduce this behavior consistently on my system. If I set a breakpoint inside the body of the loop and run until it's hit, if I then add a breakpoint at the top of the loop and hit "continue" the debugger will skip over the loop breakpoint.

I assume that this is probably because a range-based for loop expands out into a series of different initialization steps (I can actually see the temporary variables that were generated in my debug window) and the breakpoint is getting set on the initialization step rather than the loop step. If that's the case, it's understandable but surprisingly counterintuitive.

My current workaround for this issue is to set a breakpoint at the first statement inside the loop rather than at the top of the loop, but this is counterintuitive and, from a pedagogical perspective, really bad advice going forward.

My questions are the following:

1. Is my analysis correct?
2. Is this specific to my version of gdb? I'm using

   - Ubuntu 16.04 and
   - g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609.
     have
3. Is there a way to get the gdb to treat the breakpoint on the range-based for loop as a breakpoint on the loop body, not the initialization step?

Comment: "Is this OS or Qt Creator version-specific?" It could be a quirk of GDB, you might try this with Visual C++ and/or Clang and see if you get the same result. Qt Creator's debugger is just a graphical frontend, after all.

Comment: @MrEricSir Good call! Turns out this is a GDB issue! I can't seem to find anything about this with some Google searches, so I've updated the question to refocus it.

Comment: For production debugging, one could switch into assembler view, and then set the breakpoint on the iteration part of the code.  However I suspect that  "switch into assembler view" is probably not the *first* thing one should teach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting a one-to-one mapping of source code and execution that doesn't quite exist. The `for` line isn't "repeated" on each loop iteration; it only introduces and describes how the loop will operate.

It is expected behaviour that a breakpoint on the `for` line will only be hit once. I don't recall ever using a C, C++, JavaScript, whatever debugger that worked differently.

Put your breakpoint on the first line of the body, instead; it is the body that is repeated.

Comment: By the way, although it's nice to see C++11 in teaching material, you might want to consider accepting those strings by const reference. The `first + last` concatenation also seems needlessly inefficient; consider `for (char ch : boost::join(first, last))`.

Comment: I guess I'm surprised because an equivalent breakpoint in a while loop would (?) trigger a breakpoint on each iteration, hence my confusion. Also, you're absolutely right that there's unnecessary copying here, but since this is a first glimpse at C++ I think I'll hold off on showing them Boost. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef: _"I guess I'm surprised because an equivalent breakpoint in a while loop would (?) trigger a breakpoint on each iteration"_ Would it? I don't have a terminal to hand, but that's not my expectation.

Comment: I'll go test that, but from memory this would trigger on each iteration (I've debugged off-by-one errors that way.)

Comment: Yep, it will stop at the top of the while loop on each iteration.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Okay, then that is the exception to the rule. Maybe they did it that way because the `while` preamble is purely something evaluated on every iteration. Obviously that's not the case for `for`.

Comment: Both are completely consistent... the program breaks whenever the expression your cursor is inside (or nearest to, if cursor on keyword) is re-evaluated. For a `while` loop, the only expression is the continuation condition which is evaluated every loop.  For a traditional `for` loop, there are three expressions: initialization, continuation condition, and update.... and a good debugger can put a breakpoint on each of them.  For a ranged-`for`, the only expression is the one evaluated to get the container reference passed to `begin()` and `end()`, which happens only during loop initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to reproduce your sighting using `QtCreator` with `gdb` as well as with `MSVC2015`. Seems that this applies also to the regular `for(int i=0; ...)` loop - at least for my environment.

I've searched the web a bit and for `gdb` I managed to find the information in the [online doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html) which states that:

> The step command only stops at the first instruction of a source line.
>   This prevents the multiple stops that could otherwise occur in switch
>   statements, for loops, etc.

This might explain the observed behaviour. However I wasn't able to find if there is a way to disable or overwrite it.

**EDIT**

I've done some additional checking. It seems that when you step after last instruction in loop you actually go back to the `for` statement. Only the breakpoint is skipped.

In the docs in [breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#Set-Breaks) section it is stated that:

> The breakpoint will stop your program just before it executes any of
>   the code in the specified location.

This is just a wild guess but probably during the loop execution the location `just before` the breakpoint isn't reachable. Within the loop it goes only back to the condition evaluation. It has already passed the loop entry-point where some initializations occur and therefore cannot stop at breakpoint.

Comment: On the regular `for` loop, you can generally set breakpoints in three locations on the same line, corresponding to initialization, conditional exit, and increment (at least with the debugger I use most, Visual Studio, when there's more than one statement on a line, the column your cursor is in when you create the breakpoint is used to decide which statement to break on).

Comment: This might be true in general - not arguing with that. However, for `gdb` I am using with QtCreator, setting a breakpoint at for example `for(int i=0; i < text.size(); ++i)` causes my debugger to stop only once at loop entry as stated in the answer.

Comment: Doesn't it matter which part of the line you create the breakpoint for?  Breakpoint on `int i = 0` should stop once, but on `i < text.size()` should stop before each iteration, and on `++i` should stop after each iteration.  In 2016 there's no longer any excuse for debuggers to assume a 1:1 mapping between statements and source lines -- features of mid-line breakpoints and step-into-specific-function are not cutting edge.

Comment: Does it help to spread your source code over 3 lines, that is: `for( int i = 0;` (new-line) `i < text.size();` (new-line) `++i)` ?

Comment: You are correct. It helps in that way that I can stop the loop at each condition evaluation. Still the `++i` breakpoint is shifted during debug execution to the first line inside the loop - no breakpoints there for me.